# PHP extension does not compile on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: php, macos, compilation

I'm attempting to compile a PHP extension called xtree on Mac OS 10.6 but am hitting several errors about missing symbols. I've been able to compile it successfully on a machine running Debian 4 without the missing symbol errors.

The makefile appears as:

```
LIBTOOL = /usr/bin/libtool
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install

PHPINC := $(shell /opt/local/bin/php-config --includes)
PHPLIBS := $(shell /opt/local/bin/php-config --libs)
PHPDEST := $(shell /opt/local/bin/php-config --extension-dir)

XTREE_LIB = xtree2.so
OBJS = xtree.lo tree.lo node.lo parser.lo string.lo token.lo xsock.lo xpath.lo buffer.lo

.SUFFIXES : .lo .c

all : ${XTREE_LIB}

clean :
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.lo
    rm -f *.so

.c.lo :
    gcc -fpic -DHAVE_XTREE -DPIC -DCOMPILE_DL_XTREE ${PHPINC} -c -o $@ $<

${XTREE_LIB} : ${OBJS}
    gcc -shared -L/usr/local/lib -rdynamic -o ${XTREE_LIB} ${OBJS}

install : ${XTREE_LIB}
    $(INSTALL) -c ${XTREE_LIB} ${PHPDEST}/${XTREE_LIB}
```

Here are a sample of errors I am receiving when compiling on a Mac.

```
Undefined symbols:
  "__php_stream_open_wrapper_ex", referenced from:
      _tree_load_xdf in tree.lo
      _tree_save_xdf in tree.lo
      _tree_cache_control in tree.lo
      _get_cache_header in tree.lo
      _log_cache_hits in tree.lo
      _log_cache_hits in tree.lo
      _log_cache_err in tree.lo
      _buf_load_file in buffer.lo
      _buf_save_file in buffer.lo
  "_php_info_print_table_start", referenced from:
      _zm_info_xtree in xtree.lo
  "_zend_list_insert", referenced from:
      _zif_xtree_load in xtree.lo
      _zif_xtree_xchg in xtree.lo
      _zif_xtree_new in xtree.lo
```

PHP is installed on running correctly on localhost and php-config is pointing to the correct location for the includes, libs, extension-dir, etc.

Talking to some of my co-workers they suggest the linker is not correctly pointing to the libraries dynamically. However, he was unfamiliar with the Mac OS linker to know how to fix this.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've also had the following suggested to me but with no luck either:

```
Anyways, here's a few random things you could try:

- In the linker line of the Makefile (starts with "gcc -shared"), add
the "-dynamiclib" parameter after "gcc".  You may also need to remove
the "-shared" and/or "-rdynamic" parameters.

- In the linker line, add "-bundle -flat_namespace -undefined
suppress".  Again, you may need to dump "-shared" and/or "-rdynamic".
```

Still looking for help. Thanks!

Comment: Do `/opt/local/bin/php-config --libs` and the others work?  Also, I'd expect `$(PHPLIBS)` to be used somewhere.

Comment: Yes, /opt/local/bin/php-config --libs and others work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
${XTREE_LIB} : ${OBJS}
    gcc -shared -L/usr/local/lib -rdynamic -o ${XTREE_LIB} ${OBJS}
```

to this:

```
${XTREE_LIB} : ${OBJS}
    gcc -shared -L/usr/local/lib -rdynamic -o ${XTREE_LIB} ${OBJS} $(PHPLIBS)
```